# PHP namespace does not work in subdirectories

Tags: php, namespaces

I am using php namespaces and autoload. as result on top of each page I write these lines:

```
require_once('autoload.php'); // this file is in the root directory
use Lib\Blogs;
use Lib\Clients;
```

Every thing is fine with above lines when I am in root of website. But I can't access to any of them when I am in sub-directories:

I change above lines to this:

```
require_once('../autoload.php'); // this file is in the root directory
use Lib\Blogs;
use Lib\Clients;
```

and this is the error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Lib\Blogs' not found in C:\website\ajax\ajaxBlog.php on line 10
```

and in line 10, I have this code which call static method:

```
if (!empty(Blogs::findByEmail($email))) { ... }
```

Answer (score 0):

So you have to use classes with aliases or write full path when you call.

```
use Lib\Blogs as Blogs;
...
if (!empty(Blogs::findByEmail($email))) { ... }
```

or

```
if (!empty(Lib\Blogs::findByEmail($email))) { ... }
```

Comment: Do I still need autoload.php file??

Comment: Of course you need a autoloder on every page. Otherwise you have to include all class files manually. In your case you have to include autoloader file with absolute path. But it will be better if you use MVC pattern on your project. In this case you have to only one time include autoloader in index.php